# Postgres queries equivalence

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database

I would like to know if these two queries produce the same result:

```
    update A.cred
set user_name = concat(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::text)
from A.temp_table2 tt
WHERE email NOT IN (select email from A.temp_table2 it
join A.cred c on c.user_name = it.email
join A.at a on a.ld = c.ld
join A.ap ar on ar.cd = a.ad)
AND tt.email = A.cred.user_name


    update A.cred c
join A.temp_table t on t.email = c.user_name
set user_name = concat(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::text)
WHERE c.user_name NOT IN (select t.email from A.temp_table2 t
join A.cred c on c.user_name = t.email
join A.at a on a.ld = c.ld
join A.ap ar on ar.cd = a.ad)
```

Also, if any one can explain to me why one is better than the other, please enumerate for me.

Comment: The second one will not compile.

Comment: Hence, the first is better.

Comment: Apart from the fact that the second one is invalid and won't run: `concat(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::text)` makes no sense whatsoever. `user_name = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::text` is enough. But I fail to see why a column `user_name` should store the current date and time as a string value. If it's really a "user name" then this doesn't make sense. If it's indeed some date & time value, then it should be stored as `timestamp` not as `text`

Comment: @GordonLinoff but the second one is faster!